# Emacs elisp: How to change a keybind for a specific mode in evil's evil-insert-state-map

Tags: emacs, elisp

I've been using emacs for a little while now and am still trying to get the hang of elisp. In my init.el, I have the following lines:

```
(define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "RET") 'newline-and-indent)
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda () (define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "RET") 'newline)))
```

The intended effect of these two lines of elisp is to disable automatic indentation in org-mode only, but keep automatic indentation for every other mode. However, while this code does disable automatic indentation for org-mode, it has the unintended effect of disabling it for everything else as well. Does anyone know of a way to achieve the desired effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `evil-define-key`:

```
(evil-define-key 'insert org-mode-map (kbd "RET") 'newline)
```

This will define `return` to call `newline` in `insert` state only in `org-mode`.  What your hook was doing was redefining the global insert state map every time you opened an `org` buffer.